# When does Flaming Sphere do its damage if the caster delays?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, initiative

This came up recently, our wizard cast *Flaming Sphere*, and attacked an enemy with it, knocking him unconscious. The next round he wished to delay his action. When does the flaming sphere do its damage in this case? Is it also delayed or does it 'act' during the original initiative order?

Comment: Thanks for the edit @SevenSidedDie but I think I'll break the second part out into a new question as it is an oddity in and of itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly Flaming Sphere must be moved in order for it to deal damage. So until your wizard spends a move action to move the sphere (even if it damaged an enemy and the enemy did not move) it does not deal damage.